# Install Genoil failed

Tags: cpp-ethereum, genoil

Trying to install Genoil on ubuntu16 as following with GPU
https://github.com/Genoil/cpp-ethereum

Since cuda and ethminer have successfully installed  before, I just start from:

```
sudo apt-get install git cmake libcryptopp-dev libleveldb-dev libjsoncpp-dev libjsonrpccpp-dev libboost-all-dev libgmp-dev libreadline-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev ocl-icd-libopencl1 opencl-headers mesa-common-dev libmicrohttpd-dev build-essential cuda -y
```

But it said 'E: Unable to locate package cuda'

Any suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

made a script myself:

https://github.com/c2h2/eth-proxy/blob/master/install_ethminer.sh

follow install part

for cuda, you download from nvidia website. and install.

btw I have tested you don't need cuda. you just need nv display drivers.